# Up-voting a comment should work in the background

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Up-voting a comment should work in the background in the android app.

Waiting 10 seconds for one vote without doing anything makes the user uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agreed with you.

StackExchange Mobile Developer should show this processing in `ActionBar` instead of blocking complete `Activity`.

Something like , Once it has processed then you can show `Toast` about operation failed or succeeded.

[image]

Comment: Rather, I'd just see it be optimistic and pretend it's immediate, and show a toast or something if it fails.